# Connecting to DB2 for i (AS400)

Tags: c#, .net, db2-400

I am trying to write console app to connect to DB2 for i using C#. I have small code just to test the connection first but I am getting below error and I am not able find the reason for this error. And I using IBM.Data.DB2. Please throw some light.

Error Msg:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Trace' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool.GetDB2ConnPool()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ConnPool..ctor()
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Trace..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Connection..ctor(String connectionString)
   at something.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\c#\something\something\Program.cs:line 16
Press any key to continue . . .

    DB2Connection Con = new DB2Connection("Server=myserver; Database=dbname; UID=Db2admin; PWD=password;");

    DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command();

    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Reports";

    cmd.Connection = Con;

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;

    Con.Open();

    DB2DataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
```

Comment: It looks like your app can't find a driver needed to connect to DB2.  Such errors are often caused if a DLL is not in the application environment path.

Comment: Can you please tell me which dll? is it need to be in the sln directory?

Comment: @prakash try to change the connection like this `DB2Connection Con = 
new DB2Connection("Database=dbname;UserID=db2admin;Password=yourPass;Server=myserver");` ... And try to put library name before `Reports`...

Comment: Have you tried using `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries` ?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [IBM i Access Client Solutions - readme](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/as400/products/clientaccess/solutions/readmeacs.txt), your .Net data provider should be `IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries`.

You may also want to specify `NAM=1` in your [connection string](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaik/connectkeywords.htm) for system naming rules.  This will enable use of the connection job's library list to find objects, rather than hard coding schema names [ie. library names] all over the place.  This makes it easier to run in other environments (eg. testing) without having to change any source code, but just simply change the connection string to specify a different library list [`DBQ` property].